Benefits of ROS2 Control & MoveIt! for Gantry Robot
I'm currently configuring a pick-and-place machine (LumenPnP) to be interfaced with and controlled via ROS2. The machine already has an API available for direct control (Leash), which communicates with the embedded controller and firmware using G-Code.
From my understanding, it seems feasible to control and interface with the machine through a ROS node that calls the API directly. However, I'm also considering configuring the machine with ROS2 Control and MoveIt!, as this is typically done with robotic arms like the UR10e in my previous experience.
Question:
Are there any advantages or benefits to using ROS2 Control and/or MoveIt! for this particular application? Perhaps in terms of robustness or performance?
Based on my current knowledge, it doesn't seem necessary, but I'm open to insights or advice. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You are correct, it is not necessary to use ROS 2 control/MoveIt2 for your gantry-style robot. If there does not exist already some sort of Moveit configuration file, you'd have some initial overhead in setting up your robot before MoveIt can provide you with feasible plans.
If you know exactly at what position and orientation your workpiece will be arriving on the table, know the exact position of where to pick components from, and the exact position and orientation where your component should be placed, the capabilities that MoveIt can offer you won't seem very interesting.
If you already have a steady system in place (say, a sophisticated robot <-> PC setup, where the robot receives detailed instructions on the trajectory generated, where the end-effector is at each instance, and much more), then you would not find it very interesting to port everything for ROS 2 control.
Now consider the case where you need to use the same machine to work with three different parts, and you do not know what part will be arriving in the work area in advance. You decide to use a camera to determine the type of object it is, and the position of orientation of the workpiece on the work table. You can use MoveIt to create a template(plan) of the job that needs to be carried out, based on the center of each workpiece. You use the camera to detect the type of workpiece and its centre. You send this information over to your application and it computes automatically the necessary offsets required for producing the work.
This solution leaves you with two benefits:

In the future, if you need to adapt for a fourth workpiece, it's as simple as creating a new template and passing on the centre of the workpiece to have a plan that can be executed.

In the future, if you want to switch out your robot for a different one (say a UR10), you do not have to modify much of your application-level code.



Thank you for the quick response! I do agree that ROS2 Control and potentially MoveIt! would improve the robustness of the solution. However, my workmates have expressed doubts about their necessity, mainly because they've previously worked on a project with a motion platform using only the platform's Python API and regular ROS2 nodes and said it worked good enough. I believe ROS2 Control would still be useful for things like simulations and adaptability (as our robot will be picking and placing at least 3 different types of devices). Could you possibly let me know your thoughts on this?

Having ROS 2 control would surely help you out on the simulation side of things, especially for a quick test, mock_hardware is honestly a godsend. But IMO, if you are using ROS 2 control only for the simulation, you are missing out on one critical advantage that the framework offers - the same code running both on simulation and on the real robot. I would encourage you to try it out and let us know in an update how it went, and what you feel about your approach.

Thank you for the advice and insight. I think for the time being I'm going to go ahead and attempt integration w/ ROS2 Control. The potential benefits seem to outweigh any of the potential costs from my POV. I will update with how it goes once I've made some progress!
One last question. The embedded firmware for the machine currently takes in G-Code. Do you know if it's still possible to control it via ROS2 Control with this? Or would changes need to be done for the firmware?
Thank you once again for all the help!

It seems like you have to go through the code for openpnp, and see how it makes the calls to the lower level systems. Once you've figured it out, you can write your own hardware interface for your robot, or check if someone has already written one online. Regarding changes needed in the firmware itself, I don't think so - if done properly, it should not affect the core firmware of your embedded system, it simply modifies "who talks to the system", while keeping the "how we talk to it" part intact.

That makes sense. I'll give that a go!
